# Graphics cards not waking from sleep

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, suspend, hibernate

I'm fairly new to Ubuntu and Unix based systems as a whole. So far, my only concern is that my graphics cards are not waking from sleep (hibernate?) mode. When I move my mouse or hit a key on my keyboard while it is in sleep, I hear my CPU and case fans turning on. However, I do not hear my GPUs. I have two HD Radeon 6870s with AMD's proprietary driver installed from their website. I am also running Ubuntu alongside Windows using Wubi.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: first thing, it would be sleep not hibernate, Wubi doesn't support hibernation.  you say you don't hear your gpu fans running, are you getting any graphics loading?

Comment: Nothing loads. Just a black screen. If I type my password to log in then press F2 (I think?) I'm able to get to the text only interface.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to a problem that I have occasionally.  When it happens I am able to get the graphics to show by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F7 which goes to the terminal that your desktop loads on.  I have only my integrated graphics card so I have no idea if this will works for your gpu cards.   If the next time this happens Ctl+Alt+F7 does not work, this should get your desktop back but it **WILL** close all your running programs and restart your desktop so you will lose any unsaved work that was open a the time the computer suspended.

Press Ctrl+Alt+F(2-6, any will do) to get to your other terminals. enter your username and password at the prompts.  after you are logged in type the following:

```
sudo stop lightdm
```

you will get a message that says lightdm stop/wait  then type:

```
sudo start lightdm
```

this will restart your desktop and then go to your log in screen or straight to your desktop if you have it set for automatic login.